# Wrap text around very small images in latex

Tags: latex, figures

How can I wrap text around very tiny figures in latex without messing up the line margin (as it is in my example)?

[image]

Comment: FYI, this question is probably better asked on the "[tex.se]" site where the latex experts are.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "line margin"?

Answer (score 1):

Just insert directly into text with

```
Blah-blah \includegraphics[width=12pt]{imagefile} blaH-BLAH
```